# Could not run metric:all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metric-fu

I get the following error, when running `bundle exec rake metrics:all`. I dont get clue from it. Can any one help me out. Thanks in advance.

saikuro --output_directory tmp/metirc_fu/saikuro --cyclo  --filter_cyclo 0 --warn_cyclo 5 --error_cyclo 7 --formater text --input_directory app --input_directory lib 
/home/jophine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/Saikuro-1.1.0/lib/saikuro/usage.rb:4:in `require': no such file to load -- rdoc/usage (LoadError)
    from /home/jophine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/Saikuro-1.1.0/lib/saikuro/usage.rb:4:in`'
    from /home/jophine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/Saikuro-1.1.0/lib/saikuro.rb:1077:in `require'
    from /home/jophine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/Saikuro-1.1.0/lib/saikuro.rb:1077:in`'
    from /home/jophine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/Saikuro-1.1.0/lib/saikuro.rb:1069:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jophine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/Saikuro-1.1.0/bin/saikuro:91:in`require'
    from /home/jophine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/Saikuro-1.1.0/bin/saikuro:91:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jophine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/saikuro:19:in`load'
    from /home/jophine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/saikuro:19:in `<main>'
    from /home/jophine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in`eval'
    from /home/jophine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add a .metrics file in you app root and remove Saikuro and others, like below. Maybe try to use metrical gem on the top.

```
   MetricFu::Configuration.run do |config|
      config.metrics -= [:saikuro, :rcov, :roodie, :flog]
   end
```

Comment: I'm the new maintainer of metric_fu and it should work without any problems. See configuration instructions at https://github.com/metricfu/metric_fu 

Also, it works from the command-line now. Now need to bundle it or run rake or metrical